# I did dimension reduction using PCA model on Spark, but it errors as follows:

Tags: apache-spark, pca

```
16/01/13 15:34:07 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: first at RowMatrix.scala:65, took 0.013421 s
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument with more than 65535 cols: 262144
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.checkNumColumns(RowMatrix.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeCovariance(RowMatrix.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computePrincipalComponents(RowMatrix.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.PCA.fit(PCA.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansPca$delayedInit$body.apply(KMeansPca.scala:41)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansPca$.main(KMeansPca.scala:12)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansPca.main(KMeansPca.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
16/01/13 15:34:07 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/
```

how do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you have passed a Matrix with too many columns (more than 65535).

Check the code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.scala#L380) and notice that they say "Note that this cannot be computed on matrices with more than 65535 columns."

So you have to make sure that you do not have more than 65535 columns in the matrix.

Comment: But how do I train the PCA model on a matrix with more than 65535 columns. You know, in text analysis, it's very usual to represent a text to a matrix with large columns.

Comment: I do not think that this is possible, but I might be wrong. The solution that I can think about is to filter the text to reduce your vocabulary size (eliminating the stop words, stemming, eliminating the words with low DF...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it.